# How to pull the latest records from sql table to POwer BI dashboard.?

Tags: powerbi

I am a beginer to Power BI
I have loaded an sql table to power BI dataset. The table keeps udating with new records frequently. How can I always pull the data of the latest five records into the dashboard. There as id no which keeps growing with the no of rows.

another question, how can I show the dashboard specific to the current working day only? There is date stamp in the sql data. How can i use it? With filter I am able to select a particular date but to set it to current day or last week etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your data doesn't contain any field which would tell you, what then latest rows are, the there's not much you can do here. Apparently you have some sort of timestamp there, so a query something like this could work as the datasource for your report:

```
SELECT TOP 5 field1, field2... FROM Table ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

To your second question, you can add a reletive date filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range